# Flutter : Java error : duplicate class: io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, build

I'm developing an application with Flutter and I can't launch the application in debug mode on an android emulator even though it worked a few days ago. 
The error is as follows:

```
src/main/java/com/name/second_name/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:15: error: duplicate class: io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
             ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm on mac M1 with visual studio code. I tried cleaning the project with `flutter clean` but it didn't change anything and the `flutter doctor` command didn't return an error either. Don't hesitate to let me know if you need more information.

Thanks